# Why does my circle act like a rectangle in libgdx android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, physics, geometry

Like my question says can someone tell me, **why does my circle texture/sprite are acting like a rectangle** ?

Code:

`

```
@Override
public void create() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("ball.png");
    sprite = new Sprite(img);

    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2,-sprite.getHeight()/2);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -1f),true);

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set((sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth()/2) /
                    PIXELS_TO_METERS,
            (sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight()/2) / PIXELS_TO_METERS);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(sprite.getWidth()/2 / PIXELS_TO_METERS, sprite.getHeight()
            /2 / PIXELS_TO_METERS);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;

    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    shape.dispose();

    //CONTINUE

    // BOTTOM

    BodyDef bodyDefBottom = new BodyDef();
    bodyDefBottom.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    // Set the height to just 50 pixels above the bottom of the screen so we can see the edge in the
    // debug renderer
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/PIXELS_TO_METERS- 50/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    bodyDefBottom.position.set(0,0);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();

    EdgeShape edgeShape = new EdgeShape();
    edgeShape.set(-w/2,-h/2,w/2,-h/2);
    fixtureDef2.shape = edgeShape;

    bodyEdgeScreenBottom = world.createBody(bodyDefBottom);
    bodyEdgeScreenBottom.createFixture(fixtureDef2);
    edgeShape.dispose();

    // TOP

    BodyDef bodyDefTop = new BodyDef();
    bodyDefTop.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    // Set the height to just 50 pixels above the bottom of the screen so we can see the edge in the
    // debug renderer
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    bodyDefTop.position.set(0,0);
    fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();

    edgeShape = new EdgeShape();
    edgeShape.set(-w/2,h/2,w/2,h/2);
    fixtureDef2.shape = edgeShape;

    bodyEdgeScreenTop = world.createBody(bodyDefTop);
    bodyEdgeScreenTop.createFixture(fixtureDef2);
    edgeShape.dispose();

    // LEFT

    BodyDef bodyDefLeft = new BodyDef();
    bodyDefLeft.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    // Set the height to just 50 pixels above the bottom of the screen so we can see the edge in the
    // debug renderer
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    bodyDefLeft.position.set(0,0);
    fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();

    edgeShape = new EdgeShape();
    edgeShape.set(w/2,-h/2,w/2,h/2);
    fixtureDef2.shape = edgeShape;

    bodyEdgeScreenLeft = world.createBody(bodyDefLeft);
    bodyEdgeScreenLeft.createFixture(fixtureDef2);
    edgeShape.dispose();

    // RIGHT

    BodyDef bodyDefRight = new BodyDef();
    bodyDefRight.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    // Set the height to just 50 pixels above the bottom of the screen so we can see the edge in the
    // debug renderer
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/PIXELS_TO_METERS;
    bodyDefRight.position.set(0,0);
    fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();

    edgeShape = new EdgeShape();
    edgeShape.set(-w/2,-h/2,-w/2,h/2);
    fixtureDef2.shape = edgeShape;

    bodyEdgeScreenRight = world.createBody(bodyDefRight);
    bodyEdgeScreenRight.createFixture(fixtureDef2);
    edgeShape.dispose();

    //CONTINUE

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    //debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.
            getHeight());
}

private float elapsed = 0;
@Override
public void render() {
    camera.update();
    // Step the physics simulation forward at a rate of 60hz
    world.step(1f / 60f, 6, 2);

    body.applyTorque(torque, true);

    sprite.setPosition((body.getPosition().x * PIXELS_TO_METERS) - sprite.
                    getWidth() / 2,
            (body.getPosition().y * PIXELS_TO_METERS) - sprite.getHeight() / 2)
    ;
    sprite.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()));

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    //debugMatrix = batch.getProjectionMatrix().cpy().scale(PIXELS_TO_METERS,
//          PIXELS_TO_METERS, 0);
    batch.begin();

    if(drawSprite)
        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(),sprite.getOriginX(),
                sprite.getOriginY(),
                sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight(),sprite.getScaleX(),sprite.
                        getScaleY(),sprite.getRotation());

    font.draw(batch,
            "Restitution: " + body.getFixtureList().first().getRestitution(),
            -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 );
    batch.end();

    //debugRenderer.render(world, debugMatrix);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    img.dispose();
    world.dispose();
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}


// On touch we apply force from the direction of the users touch.
// This could result in the object "spinning"
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    body.applyForce(1f,1f,screenX,screenY,true);
    //body.applyTorque(0.4f,true);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
```

`

I have tried searching for other posts but couldn't find anything that explains to me why it is acting like a rectangle and how to resolve this. I have also tried searching for other methods to draw the texture , even using CircleShape but that cannot put inside texture from image. I'm pretty newbie in libgdx, I'm still learning everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm little confused... You are creating **PolygonShape** and expecting it will behave as circle?

```
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(...
```

All you can achieve this way is **polygon** with ball sprite inside. If you want to have a circle use mentioned by you **CircleShape**

```
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(1); //or anything you need

    ...

    //assing it to the fixture etc
```

then update it when drawing with its position and **angle** - that's all

Comment: I have tried that before this , but the ball don't even move :/ . Anyway thanks, now i know which was the right way.

Comment: It was the radius of shape. I have been assigned to it the sprite.getHeight()/2 , and it was to big , i replace that by sprite.getHeight()/PIXELS_TO_METERS/2 and works great, thanks a lot ^^